# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name usuario was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: java, postgresql

I am getting the following error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name usuario was not found in this ResultSet.

However, I have the following column usuario declared properly in the appropriate classes!

UsuariosGruposDAO.class

```
public Object objectFactory(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            UsuariosGrupos usergroup = new UsuariosGrupos(rs.getString("usuario"), rs.getString("grupo"));
            return usergroup;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // retorno do método
            return null;
        }
    }
```

UsuariosGrupos.class

```
public class UsuariosGrupos {

    private String usuario;
    private String grupo;

    public UsuariosGrupos() {
    }

    public UsuariosGrupos(String usuario, String grupo) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.grupo = grupo;
    }
```

The error appears in the following line:

```
       ugList.add((UsuariosGrupos) objectFactory(rs));
```

of my List method:

```
List<UsuariosGrupos> ugList = null;
    try {
        //Conecta no banco
        conn.conectar();
        //Prepara o preparedStatment
        stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.getPreparedStatement("SELECT * from usuarios_grupos");
        //Executa a instrucao SQL
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        ugList = new ArrayList<UsuariosGrupos>();
        //Enquanto ouver resultSet
        while (rs.next()) {
            ugList.add((UsuariosGrupos) objectFactory(rs));
        }
        System.out.println("################################UsuariosGrupos OK################################");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("################################UsuariosGrupos Falhou################################");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn.desconectar();
    }
    return ugList;
}
```

The weird thing is when I test my List separately, the datatable displays the appropriate results. However, when I run my entire application, nothing shows up, and I get that error stating the column usuario cannot be found in the resultset. Any suggestions?

The table has two fields:

```
Usuarios | Grupos

admin        2
admin        3
```

It displays fine, when I separate my jsf code, but doesn't display the data when I have it on one JSF file.

Comment: Could we see the structure of the table "usuarios_grupos"?

Comment: I think @Gray has the correct answer - when you are retrieving items from a resultset by name, you need to specify the name of the column on the database, not the name of the property of the object that you ultimately want to set.

Comment: in PostgreSQL, names are case-sensitive. "Usuarios" is not the same as "usuarios"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your table dump shows the field as "Usarios" but you are doing a `rs.getString("usuario")`.  Shouldln't that be the following?

```
rs.getString("usuarios")
```

If that doesn't work then I would recommend debugging your code, putting a breakpoint on the `getString` line and looking at the `ResultSet` to see what the field names are there.