# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name grupo was not found in this ResultSet. (DIFFERENT ERROR)

Tags: java, postgresql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name usuario was not found in this ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793399/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-the-column-name-usuario-was-not-found-in-this)

I apologize for asking the question with the similar error. However, this one is different.

So my database table for usuarios_grupos is the following:

```
usuario | grupo

admin   | 1
admin   | 1
erion   | 5
```

My result set method is the following:

```
public Object objectFactory(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            UsuariosGrupos usergroup = new UsuariosGrupos(rs.getString("usuario"), rs.getString("grupo"));
            return usergroup;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // retorno do método
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The error appears at the same line:

```
ugList.add((UsuariosGrupos) objectFactory(rs));
```

in my List method:

```
public List<UsuariosGrupos> select() {
    //Colecao List recebe null
    List<UsuariosGrupos> ugList = null;
    try {

        //Conecta no banco
        conn.conectar();
        //Prepara o preparedStatment
        stmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.getPreparedStatement("select * from usuarios_grupos");
        //Executa a instrucao SQL
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        ugList = new ArrayList<UsuariosGrupos>();
        //Enquanto ouver resultSet
        while (rs.next()) {
            ugList.add((UsuariosGrupos) objectFactory(rs));
        }
        System.out.println("################################UsuariosGrupos OK################################");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("################################UsuariosGrupos Falhou################################");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        conn.desconectar();
    }
    return ugList;
}
```

This is my UsuariosGrupos model:

```
  public class UsuariosGrupos {

    private String usuario;
    private String grupo;

    public UsuariosGrupos() {
    }

    public UsuariosGrupos(String usuario, String grupo) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.grupo = grupo;
    }

   public String getGrupo() {
        return grupo;
    }

    public void setGrupo(String grupo) {
        this.grupo = grupo;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }


}
```

I don't get it. My result set matches that of my database, and yet I am getting the error. Same letter-casing. Does anyone know what I've done wrong : /

The usuario and grupo in my usuarios_grupos is a primary composite key. Do you think it might have anything to do with the error?? Thanks!

Comment: Post the stack trace of the SQLException, and NEVER use `select *`. Always select the columns you want, explicitely.

Comment: why are you returning `Object` in your `objectFactory()` method if it's hardcoded to return `UsuariosGrupos` only?

Comment: I seriously doubt this is any different from your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793399/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-the-column-name-usuario-was-not-found-in-this

Given your post history and the number of questions on this trivial piece of code (or otherwise: very similar pieces of code) over the past three months, I strongly advise you to practice your debugging skills and SQL knowledge and not run to StackOverflow for every hurdle you run into.

Answer (score 1):

From your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793399/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-the-column-name-usuario-was-not-found-in-this), your table seems to look as follows:

```
Usuarios | Grupos

admin        2
admin        3
```

Then your `ResultSet` should be `rs.getString("Grupos");`

Comment: I made changes to the table by changing them to lower-case usuario and grupo. So, I made the changes to my rs.getString("usuario") and rs.getString("grupo")

Answer (score 0):

I would query the ResultSetMetaData to check what columnLabels it thinks it actually has available for you.

Also: be explicit when making queries. Don't use `SELECT *`, but assign explicit columnnames (in this case: you would get the error earlier if there really is no column `grupos`.